# Mercurial's showconfig with the proper encoding?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, mercurial

I want to get the root path to my Mercurial repository using `hg showconfig` then retrieving `bundle.mainreporoot`. The root path has non-ASCII characters, it is `D:\maçã\asd`.

The output of `hg showconfig` is:

```
...
bundle.mainreporoot=D:\maþÒ\asd
...
```

I'm running this in a Windows 7 Powershell that has encoding cp850. I want to tell Mercurial to output showconfig with the proper encoding cp850. I have tried for example `hg showconfig --encoding cp850` with no success.

The character `þ` is in cp850 `\xE7` which looks like the unicode code point U+00E7 for `ç` (the correct character I need), and is also `ç` in cp1252.

Comment: Would it not make more sense to have the shell use a sensible encoding (utf-8)? Or is there some deep reason why you need to use codepages, which are recognised as obsolete?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, Windows notoriously sucks at UTF-8, esp. in a console.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: this is PowerShell, not the normal terminal. It should be able to cope with Unicode (UTF-16LE if not UTF-8), so long as it's being run in the PowerShell terminal, not being run in the system terminal, I believe?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, that hasn't been my experience.  Both consoles handle it badly.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: OK, I yield. I've never tried anything in that direction, just heard that it was meant to be fixed up.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Granted, I haven't used PowerShell much, so as a test I made a simple C exe that used `wprintf(L"maçã");`.  PowerShell still displayed it incorrectly until the code page was set to 1252.  But I could set the code page to 65001 (UTF-8) and explicitly `printf("ma\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3");` and get the correct output. Same result with the legacy console.  So partly it is the programs not encoding to the console correctly.  `hg` is returning the strings in cp1252 on US Windows no matter the console encoding.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: console window is the same regardless of command interpreter used (neither cmd nor PowerShell own or draw the window, it's hardwired into OS components).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the code page before running the command helps.  US Windows uses cp437 for consoles and Windows-1252 for non-Unicode GUI programs.  For whatever reason, Mercurial is using cp1252.  If you aren't using US Windows, you may need a different code page.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS W:\maçã\asd> hg showconfig bundle.mainreporoot
W:\maτπ\asd
PS W:\maçã\asd> chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252
PS W:\maçã\asd> hg showconfig bundle.mainreporoot
W:\maçã\asd
```

**Edit**

According to Python3, the three different strings you've been seeing are the cp1252 returned by Mercurial and decoded in the console as cp850 or cp437:

```
>>> 'maçã'.encode('cp1252').decode('cp850')
'maþÒ'
>>> 'maçã'.encode('cp1252').decode('cp437')
'maτπ'
```

Your pastebin code is cp850 decoded as cp1252:

```
>>> 'maçã'.encode('cp850').decode('cp1252')
'ma‡Æ'
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is what I got:
`PS C:\Users\Falcπo\asd> chcp
\n Active code page: 437 \n
PS C:\Users\Falcπo\asd> hg showconfig bundle.mainreporoot \n
C:\Users\Falcπo\asd \n
PS C:\Users\Falcπo\asd> chcp 1252 \n
Active code page: 1252 \n
PS C:\Users\Falcπo\asd> hg showconfig bundle.mainreporoot \n
C:\Users\Falcπo\asd`
This was run on a different computer than the computer I used in the question. The output of showconfig should be `C:\Users\Falcão\asd`. I can retry your solution later on that first computer.

Comment: @STALTZ, even your powershell prompt shows the incorrect value.  Note that mine doesn't, even when Hg is wrong.  Since your code page shows it defaults to cp437, do you need cp850 instead?

Comment: Try to ignore my first comment. I just ran it on the same computer I used for the question, and I got a funny result: http://pastebin.com/QzCCfhCM. Any way, I think I've solved my problem now. Actually I'm not directly using PowerShell, but I have a Python script that is executing shell programs through Popen, including Mercurial, so I've found a way of getting the proper output from showconfig. Your hint about "For whatever reason, Mercurial is using cp1252" was enough for me, that's why I'm marking it solved.

Comment: I would +1 the answer if the mystery at pastebin got understood